# Could not write in file "pg_subtrans/000B" with pgAdmin 4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

In pg_admin 4 when i'm trying to create a new database I have this error :

`ERROR : could not access status of transaction 0 DETAIL : Could not write to file pg_subtrans/000B" at offset 131072 : No space left on device`

My disk have a lot of gigas free (33GB).

More information : When I want to open the list of tables, it takes more time than usual.

I don't know where I can find this file, and if i can delete it or something, or how to repair this error.

Thanks

Comment: Hej Vincent, could it be that your tablespace is pointing to another device? In case you didn't change the default tablespace, check also if the partition where postgres is installed has enough space.

Comment: Just a guess: maybe there is free space on the file system, but you are out of inodes? What is the operating system and the file system you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution, on the server where postgres is installed, we have a limit of size per user. The administrator inscreased it and I don't have the error anymore.

I'll edit this post when i'll have more informations.